# Free variables in R for computer-assisted mathematical analysis

Tags: r, variables, math, linear-algebra

Globally speaking, how do we deal/create free variables in R?

For example, I'd like to create and multiply the following matrices:

```
mat1 = matrix(c(x,2*x,3,4), nrow=2)
mat2 = matrix(c(1,x,x/2,3), nrow=2)
mat1 %*% mat2
```

, where `x` is not an object that had been a priori defined but is a variable free to take any number later in the program.

Comment: There might be a package for that somewhere, but I'm pretty sure you can't do that kind of thing in R. `yacas` is a nice package that can do linear algebra, in the way that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Ryacas](http://ryacas.googlecode.com) package:

```
> library(Ryacas)
> x <- Sym("x")
> mat1 <- List(List(x, 3), List(2*x, 4))
> PrettyForm(mat1)
/                  \
| ( x )     ( 3 )  |
|                  |
| ( 2 * x ) ( 4 )  |
\                  /
> mat2 <- List(List(1, x/2), List(x, 3))
> PrettyForm(mat2)
/              \
| ( 1 ) / x \  |
|       | - |  |
|       \ 2 /  |
|              |
| ( x ) ( 3 )  |
\              /
> PrettyForm(mat1*mat2)
/                                    \
| ( 4 * x )         /  2     \       |
|                   | x      |       |
|                   | -- + 9 |       |
|                   \ 2      /       |
|                                    |
| ( 2 * x + 4 * x ) /      2      \  |
|                   | 2 * x       |  |
|                   | ------ + 12 |  |
|                   \   2         /  |
\                                    /
```